# Issue with firebase V9 onSnapshot function

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Due to certain changes in react native, I have to use the latest version of firebase that is 9.17.1; however, the onSnapshot function is not working with this version. Below you will find a copy of my code.

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    measurementId: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
export default db;
```

Homescreen.js

```
import db from '../firebase'
import { collection, FieldValue, query, serverTimestamp, where, doc, getDoc, getDocs, updateDoc, orderBy } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
//...other imports
async componentDidMount() {
    this.getRequestedChatList()
    this.getRequestedData()
    this.getRequestedPosts()
    //...other functions
}
//The below function with getDocs works
getRequestedPosts = async () => {
    const postsCollection = collection(db, 'Posts');
    const postsSnapshot = await getDocs(postsCollection)
    const postList = postsSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    this.setState({ isPostLoaded: true });
    this.setState({ Posts: postList });
}
//The below function is with onSnapshot
getRequestedPosts = async () => {
    onSnapshot(collection(db, 'Posts'), (snapshot) => {
        const postList = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        console.log(postList)
        this.setState({ isPostLoaded: true, posts: postList });
    });
}
```

Please help me out.

Note: I am not sure what, but it causes error related to internet but if I import it from lite it works. And I am getting error ERROR [2023-03-05T03:04:18.740Z] @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.17.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend when using firebase/firestore insted of firebase/firestore/lite

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can mix the lite and regular versions of the Firestore SDK in the way that you are doing.

If you need `onSnapshot`, consider importing all functions from the regular SDK:

```
import { collection, FieldValue, query, serverTimestamp, where, doc, getDoc, 
         getDocs, updateDoc, orderBy, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';
```

And:

```
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
```

Comment: I am not sure what, but it causes the data get from getDoc or getDocs and it also causes the query and where thing and if i import it from lite it works. And I am getting error  ERROR  [2023-03-05T03:04:18.740Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.17.1): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend when using firebase/firestore insted of firebase/firestore/lite